# How to drop a git repository into an existing directory

Tags: git, unix

I'm trying to add an existing git repo to a directory.

Specifically, my home directory is a git repository and it tracks a few file for me. (.zprofile, .vimrc, ect) I'm trying to find a way to clone my repository into this directory on different systems, so that every time I make changes they will automatically sync with every system that I use.

The main issue is that when I clone my git repo with my dot files into my home directory, they're added in their own folder, separate from the rest of my home directory. So the .vimrc, and so on isn't directly accessible by those programs. I know that I can manually move all the files out of the sub-folder into the home directory, and they still should still be tracked and everything, I'm just curious as to whether or not there is a way to solve this problem within git.

```
git clone https://github.com/makccr/dotProfiles.git mack
fatal: destination path 'mack' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Comment: Is mack your home folder? `cd ~` Then `git clone https://github.com/makccr/dotProfiles.git .`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clone%5D+non-empty+folder